# how to get key value pairs from a pay slip document using Google document AI

Tags: cloud-document-ai

So i am working to get pay slips from scanned pages into a spreadsheet. I would like to make a google document AI to do so.

here is what one page looks like (redacted personal information)
[picture of pay stub sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj9Gw.png)

obviously the problem here is that many clients are represented here on one page. So just pointing OCR at it wont help me without a human parsing that.

what is the best method to train the AI to essentially chunk up the document  into client or even better create a key value structure where each client name corresponds to the information listed in their row.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [Pay Slip parser](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_pay-slip-parser) to parse this document, which will extract named entities specific to Pay Stub documents.

You can use this demo application to test out the Pay Slip parser performance on a few test documents as well:

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/drag-and-drop

You can also use [Uptraining](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/training-overview#uptrain) to improve the accuracy on your specific documents or extract additional entities than the ones that are extracted by default.

You can use this code sample to get the entities from an entity extraction processor.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#entities

Or, if you're using Python, you can use the [Document AI Toolbox SDK](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#quickstart) to more easily extract the entities after sending the document to the processor.